# mongodb - in operator - ignore object key order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db.mice.find({'strains': {$in : [{mode:'++',name:'Str1'},{mode:'++',name:'Str2'}]}}).count() 
// returns 0
db.mice.find({'strains': {$in : [{name:'Str1',mode:'++'},{name:'Str2',mode:'++'}]}}).count()
// returns 1
```

How do you make the same query but ignore the order of the key/value pair within the object?

Comment: $in works independent of the ordering of elements with the array. what issue are you getting.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) instead of `$in` in this case:

```
db.mice.find({'strains': {$elemMatch: {mode:'++', name:'Str1'}}}).count()
```

The reason `$in` doesn't work is that it operates on matching the entire value against the elements of the array field, so because you're providing an object, the object must match exactly, including field order.

The `$elemMatch` value, however, is interpreted as a query object, not a single value, so field order doesn't matter.

Comment: Item 1 in this list discusses this behaviour:  [http://devblog.me/wtf-mongo](http://devblog.me/wtf-mongo)

Comment: thanks but.. what about db.mice.find({'strains': {$in : [{name:'Str1',mode:'++'},{name:'Str2',mode:'++'}]}}).count()

Comment: @arx Presumably that returns a count of 1 because there's a doc that contains a `strains` array that contains one of those exact objects.

Comment: i managed to solve the problem by replicating the elemMatch against all the elements in the array since $in only matches object keys that are in the same order. i suppose this is is because mongodb iterates through the keys in order and matches them that way which probably more efficient anyhow